# Generator function doesn't have desired functionality (Angular 5)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

This is my first time using a generator function so sorry if Im using it incorrectly..

Okay so basically I have a button that will order a list of users, there's 3 order options - order by whos available, whos unavailable and then by Name.

Now I want to cycle through these options so everytime you click the button it just orders it by the next `yield` and so on and so forth.

So I've created a function like so..

```
*order() {
   yield this.crewMembers = _.orderBy(this.crewMembers, ['available'], ['asc']);
   yield this.crewMembers = _.orderBy(this.crewMembers, ['available'], ['desc']);
   yield this.crewMembers = _.orderBy(this.crewMembers, ['username'], ['desc']);
}
```

then in my html

```
<button (click)="order().next()">ORDER</button>
```

now it works the first time, it changes the order to `available`, `asc` but it doesnt work if I click the button again;

my desired outcome is to be able to press the button infinitely and cycle through my order options.. am I doing this right??

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you call `order()`, you are starting a new instance of the generator from the beginning.  You need to call `order()` once, save it in a variable, and then call `.next()` on that variable each time the button is clicked.

Comment: How Do I restart the function once its been complete?

Comment: You could just add a `while (true)` loop around the yield statements.